# How to see web requests in Google chrome inspector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Trying to scrape postcode information from https://www.thameswater.co.uk/your-account/605.htm. Want to see the web requests after I enter a postcode

I Open developer tools open up the Chrome inspector on the postcode search box

Typed in a London postcode , hit enter , but how do i look at the web requests that are sent and see the specific one that takes the postcode I typed in?

Comment: Do you have it set to show all requests in the network tab?

Comment: See the network tab in inspector..

Comment: More info on the network tab can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check  **'Network'** tab/menu to see web requests in Google chrome inspector

For more details you can also check :  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network